# Unexpected grouping in pandas groupby

Tags: python, pandas

New to pandas, so I may be missing something obvious here. My intent is to simply list top projects by efforts, grouped by type. Here the CSV I'm working with as input:

```
project,effort,type
p1,6,feature
p2,4.5,feature
p3,4.375,bug
p4,4,bug
p5,3.875,bug
p6,3.5,upgrade
p7,3.5,feature
p8,3,upgrade
p9,2,upgrade
```

Now my intent is to show top 3 projects by effort, grouped by type. This is what I did:

```py
dev=pd.read_csv('test.csv')
dev.sort_values(['effort'], ascending=False).groupby('type').head(3)
```

This is what I see in ipython:

```
  project  effort     type
0      p1   6.000  feature
1      p2   4.500  feature
2      p3   4.375      bug
3      p4   4.000      bug
4      p5   3.875      bug
5      p6   3.500  upgrade
6      p7   3.500  feature
7      p8   3.000  upgrade
8      p9   2.000  upgrade
```

Though the rows seem accurate, I expected the output to have features, bugs and upgrades grouped together, even if that meant that the efforts were not strictly sorted in descending order, like this:

Expected:

```
  project  effort     type
0      p1   6.000  feature
1      p2   4.500  feature
6      p7   3.500  feature
2      p3   4.375      bug
3      p4   4.000      bug
4      p5   3.875      bug
5      p6   3.500  upgrade
7      p8   3.000  upgrade
8      p9   2.000  upgrade
```

That is, all features, followed by bugs, followed by upgrades (not needed in the same order, but at least grouped by correctly).

Am I missing something obvious? Thanks in advance for your replies!

Comment: `df.sort_values(['type', 'effort'], ascending=False)` ?

Comment: @akilat90 I need the top 3 of each type. I don't think this works?

Comment: I've missed it - just tried to match the expected output without reading. Does this work? `df.sort_values('effort', ascending=False).groupby(['type']).head(3).sort_values('type')`

Comment: The sorting should be by effort (descending).

Comment: I think the initial sorting addresses that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Update:**

First `sort` according to the `effort`. `groupby` the `type`, take `head` and then `sort` by `type` again.

```
df.sort_values('effort', ascending=False).groupby(['type']).head(3).sort_values('type')
```

Comment: Apologies, I edited the question to show my expected output. I am not interested in sum, but top 3 projects of each type (in terms of efforts)

Comment: @ragebiswas answer updated. I think this should work.

Comment: Thanks, this works - didn't realize I need an extra 'sort'! Wondering if there's a simpler way though :)

Comment: @ragebiswas Not that I can think of. The second sort is mandatory because the `type` level sorting should not interfere with the `effort` level sorting.

Answer (score 1):

In the provided sample dataset each project is a single record with a specific type. In this case we can get top 3 projects by effort with `nlargest` and then `groupby` type and `sum` the efforts:

```
df.nlargest(3, 'effort').groupby('type').sum()
```

Output:

```
         effort
type           
bug       4.375
feature  10.500
```

P.S. Here's to explain a bit what went wrong with

```
dev.sort_values(['effort'], ascending=False).groupby('type').head(3)
```

When you use `head` on a `GroupBy` object, it takes the first elements for each group (see the doc for [`head`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.core.groupby.GroupBy.head.html)), so you get top 3 for each of 'feature', 'bug', and 'upgrade'. If you apply `head` before `groupby` it would work correctly:

```
dev.sort_values(['effort'], ascending=False).head(3).groupby('type').sum()
```

It is basically the same thing as in my solution above, with the only difference that I used `nlargest` instead of sorting and applying `head` afterwards (`nlargest` is just a bit more concise)

**Update:** you can pre-sort by both type (ascending) and effort (descending) + `groupby` and `head`:

```
df.sort_values(['type', 'effort'], ascending=[1,0]).groupby('type').head(3)
```

Output:

```
  project  effort     type
2      p3   4.375      bug
3      p4   4.000      bug
4      p5   3.875      bug
0      p1   6.000  feature
1      p2   4.500  feature
6      p7   3.500  feature
5      p6   3.500  upgrade
7      p8   3.000  upgrade
8      p9   2.000  upgrade
```

Apparently, there's an open issue for that in `pandas` discussed [`here`](https://github.com/pandas-dev/pandas/issues/17775)

Comment: Apologies, I edited the question to show expected output. My only concern is regarding the ordering of rows in the output. I don't need the sum.

Comment: @ragebiswas: you can pre-sort by type and effort, then everything works fine (see my update). What you got here seems to be an open issue in `pandas`, I've included the link if you want to check this out

Comment: Thank you @perl. I must confess some of the details in the github issue are beyond my level of pandas expertise at the moment, but I'm surely going through it. FWIW your updated solution works perfectly too - thank you!

Answer (score 0):

`head(3)` is at least the size of each group and therefore prints the entire `DataFrame`.

```
import pandas as pd
import csv
from pandas.compat import StringIO

print(pd.__version__)

csvdata = StringIO("""project,effort,type
p1,6,feature
p2,4.5,feature
p3,4.375,bug
p4,4,bug
p5,3.875,bug
p6,3.5,upgrade
p7,3.5,feature
p8,3,upgrade
p9,2,upgrade""")

df = pd.read_csv(csvdata, sep=",")

print(df)
print(df.sort_values(['effort'], ascending=False).groupby('type').head(1))
```

Produces

```
0.24.2
  project  effort     type
0      p1   6.000  feature
1      p2   4.500  feature
2      p3   4.375      bug
3      p4   4.000      bug
4      p5   3.875      bug
5      p6   3.500  upgrade
6      p7   3.500  feature
7      p8   3.000  upgrade
8      p9   2.000  upgrade
  project  effort     type
0      p1   6.000  feature
2      p3   4.375      bug
5      p6   3.500  upgrade
```

But the MCVE code shows only the use of a `Grouper`.  An function such as `mean()` will be more useful.

Comment: I've given a simplified input. Even if the input has 9 rows and all need to be output,  I expect the grouping to hold.